# Action and Function onClick with same button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, popup

I have 2 buttons:

```
< button onClick= {() => { actions.showInfoOnHover(movie)}}> Show Info < /button>
< button onClick={this.open}> Show Info < /button>
```

First one is calling a redux  action, second one is just a simple function:

```
open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }
```

First button get the information for my Popup, second one fires Popup itself. Is there any easy way to combine these together?

---

Udpate: 
I tried to combine it like

```
open() {
    actions.showInfoOnHover(movie);
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }



 < button onClick={this.open}> Show Info  </ button>
```

in this case both action and Popup does not work: action does not pass the data, Popup does not show.

Comment: When you combine them into one, what is the problem. Are you not getting the information or the modal is not opening

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thank you for reply! If I combine them, both action and Popup does not work: action does not pass the data, Popup does not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you might be missing

**Firstly**, when calling the open function you need to pass the movie parameter since you need it for getting the info or you need to use it from props

**Secondly**, you should return a promise from the action so that you can open the modal once the information is ready

You code must look like

```
open() {
    this.props.actions.showInfoOnHover(this.props.movie)
        .then((res) => {
             this.setState({ showModal: true });
         })

}

< button onClick={this.open}> Show Info < /button>
```

> P.S. One other thing you need to check is whether you have properly
>   dispatched the action

After seeing your code it seems that you are not having an API call to get the information, so you can simply use

```
open() {
    actions.showInfoOnHover(this.props.movie)
    this.setState({ showModal: true });

}

< button onClick={this.open}> Show Info < /button>
```

Comment: @Polina, can you try this answer and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Shubham Khatri,  Thank you for reply and help! In this particular case I do not need to pass movie parameter, because I am using redux-bootstrap and I have passed what I need in my render. If I leave these 2 buttons separate, they do the job: first one passes the information I need, second one shows Popup with this information. May be you can take a look at whole file if it helps?    https://github.com/polinazolotukhina/redux-movieDB/blob/master/src/components/FavouritesButton.js

Comment: @Polina, I say you code, you can indeed modify your code to use props instead of passing the variable but you do need it to be present in open function, check the update

Comment: I tried your code, it did nothing and in console I can see the error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. IF I console movie open(movie) {
    this.props.actions.showInfoOnHover(movie)
    console.log(movie)
        .then((res) => {
             this.setState({ showModal: true });
         })

} it will show the correct object that was passed to movie

Comment: Polina, as I said you need to return promise from the action before using .then

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, if I try "this.props.movie" the error is Cannot read property 'then' of undefined. If i tried just 'movie' the error is 'movie is not defined'. I also   added  'this.prop' to this.props.actions.showInfoOnHover, otherwise it complains.

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen the update bellow! It works after small edit!!!!  the final code is  : open() {
    this.props.actions.showInfoOnHover(this.props.movie);
    this.setState({ showModal: true });

} Thank you for the help!!!:)

Comment: yeah you are right, I saw the movie part but missed the action part